# Not able to read InDesign XMP File through ExtendScript and write in external xml

Tags: adobe-indesign, extendscript, xmp

I am using InDesign 2020/2021, on my Windows 10. When I am trying to get XMP data for my .indd (InDesign document) using ExtendScript, The below line gives an error on the Adobe Extenscript toolkit

```
xmpFile = new XMPFile(myFile.fsName, XMPConst.FILE_INDESIGN, XMPConst.OPEN_FOR_UPDATE);
```

[image]

The is the data I want to write/read from InDesign
[image]

Can please someone suggest, how can I read all the XMP data and write it in an XML file

Comment: Are you wanting to programmatically write the xmp packet to a file? Is the resultant file that you want the same as choosing:  `File` > `File Info` > `Export` from the menu bar ?

Comment: @Robc yes, I want the same file Info to read and get some values

Comment: Added Image for the raw data which I want to access & get details using extendscript